# Модификация Java-байткода при компиляции

Tags: java, компилятор

Какие есть способы изменения Java-байткода во время/после компиляции?
Меня интересует возможность за счёт аннотаций модифицировать классы, как это делает lombok.
Например, у того жe lombok есть [val](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), мне нужны подобные инструменты (например, для реализация async/await как в node.js)

Comment: Для DEX (Android) существует smali-baksmali, он же apktool, хороший дизассемблер и "ассемблер обратно". Для стандартного - возможен "костыль" из dx + dex2jar для конвертирования в DEX и обратно, и опять же какие-то дизассемблеры. Стандартный javap не может собирать обратно, только дизассемблирует.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/